# What is the meaning of "topmost" in the alMostTop alignment in TAlignLayout?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In the [documentation for TAlignLayout](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Types.TAlignLayout), a type which addresses visual alignment settings for FireMonkey controls, I'm trying to figure out the difference between the `alTop` and `alMostTop` constants, the only difference is that the definition of `alMostTop` contains the phrase "set to be the topmost".

(The same goes for the constants `alMostLeft`, `alMostRight` and `alMostBottom`, which are distinguished from `alLeft`, `alRight` and `alBottom` with similar phrases using the words
"leftmost", "rightmost" and "bottommost".)

I don't know what "set to be the topmost" means, and none of the guesses I make seem to fit with observed FireMonkey behaviour:

- If it means displaying that control on top (at the front of the display) relative to its siblings, then what does leftmost mean?
- If "leftmost" means it is the sibling shown furthest to the left, out of all siblings that have a `alLeft` alignment, then why does the CustomListBox demo use a layout with two elements that have a `alMostLeft` alignment? How does it decide to place the two elements that particular way round?

The Embarcadero forums don't shed any light on this either.

[Update]

To be clear, experiments do indeed suggest that with two components aligned to the top, you can choose which one is to be further up the screen by setting that one to have `alMostTop`, and the other to `alTop`.

However, I thought of another possibility: suppose you have two child components, one to be aligned at the left, another aligned at the top. Then they will fight for ownership of the top-left corner. Experiments seem to suggest that some influence can be obtained by choosing between `alTop` and `alMostLeft` alignments for the two controls vs `alMostTop` and `alLeft` alignments.  I can't see exactly what is going on here, and it's not clear in the documentation. It's also not clear what should/might happen if two child controls are both set to `alMostTop`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have 2 (or more) controls aligned to top, the alMostTop will be on the top of all others. Same wise with alMostRight, alMostLeft, and alMostBottom.

Comment: The phrase "on the top of" doesn't explain any more than "topmost". It could mean "further up the screen" or "visually at the front". Assuming it means "further up" (otherwise "leftmost" doesn't make sense), that doesn't explain what is supposed to happen when two controls are both marked `alMostTop`.